# Appcelerator ERROR | socket hang up

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to package my app for android app store via the appcelerator studio but after processing the javascript files the console displays this error

2017-04-17T22:47:39.618Z | ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
socket hang up
2017-04-17T22:47:39.619Z | ERROR  | socket hang up

I packaged the app to the play store successfully a few weeks ago and the app runs fine in the iOS simulator.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: Try to logout from the AppC Studio and then login in again. If the issue still persists try to build it in an open network (without firewall restrictions) and see if that helps. As @Prashant mentioned, it is with the token. You can also try appc login from the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try updating your appc version.  I was on 5.4.0 and began getting that error at the end of last week.  After updating to 6.0.0 my problem was fixed:

```
appc use 6.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not any SDK error, but this is rather a case where Studio tries to acccess Appcelerator server for some internal calls like validating app with your Dashboard and checking your Appc. account organisation data.

Most likely this issue is resolved if you clean your project & build it again with a proper network availability.

Note that Studio needs network access to run app for the first time, then it saves the access token locally and you can run app further without network access.

If this issue still persists, then you can run this command ***appc login*** from terminal or command prompt. This method has always worked for me as SOCKET HANGUP issue is totally a network issue.